# FFmpeg: Change centered Zoom In effect command to Zoom Out

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have the ***centered Zoom In*** effect command which works perfectly. Here is the command

```
fmpeg -y -r 25 \ 
-loop 1 -t 6 -i 1.jpg \ 
-loop 1 -t 6 -i 2.jpg \ 
-loop 1 -t 6 -i 3.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 6 -i 4.jpg \
-i audio.mp3 \
[0]crop=1280:1280,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':s=1280x1280:d=700:x='if(gte(zoom,1.5),x,x+1/a)':y='if(gte(zoom,1.5),y,y+1)'[v1];
[1]crop=1280:1280,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':s=1280x1280:d=700:x='if(gte(zoom,1.5),x,x+1/a)':y='if(gte(zoom,1.5),y,y+1)'[v2];
[2]crop=1280:1280,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':s=1280x1280:d=700:x='if(gte(zoom,1.5),x,x+1/a)':y='if(gte(zoom,1.5),y,y+1)'[v3];
[3]crop=1280:1280[v4];
[v1][v2]xfade=rectcrop:duration=1:offset=5[x1];
[x1][v3]xfade=distance:duration=1:offset=10[x2];
[x2][v4]xfade=wiperight:duration=1:offset=15,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 4:a -b:v 4000k -movflags +faststart -s 1280x1280 zoomin.mp4
```

So, I need to make the ***centered Zoom Out*** effect. Honestly, I'm not exactly sure what every parameter means in the current ***zoompan*** filter but I've tried to do some changes / manipulations with the current one ( for example, changed `zoom+0.0015`, changed `1.5`, changed `x+1`, `y+1` to `x-1`, `y-1`) to get the desired result but nothing works.

Looking forward to any help / guide / solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set z to `1.5-0.0015*on`. `1.5` is the initial zoom and 0.0015 is the reduction in zoom level per frame.

For x and y, use `x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)'`

Comment: Thanks. This works, but the zoom is not centered like it was for Zoom In. It's like zooming the top left section of the image

Comment: See edited cmd.